# How to extract value of a variable from one public method and call into another method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, ionic4

I have a method StepsCount where i am getting series of timestamps data. i would like to call timeSeries into another component, i have inheirted this class method but i am not sure how to get the data (timeSeries) out of this method.

```
//Main method where data sits in timeSeries 
public StepsCount(): Observable<any> {
if (this.patientIdentifierCache !== undefined) {
  this.getAllObservations(this.patientIdentifierCache, function(
    allObservations
  ) {

    timeSeries = allObservations.temperature;
    const filter = new DateFilter();
    filter.datePoint = new Date(2005, 9, 10);

    timeSeries = timeSeries.filter(filter.getDateFilter());

    return timeSeries;
  });

}
return Observable.of( timeSeries);
```

}

```
//Second method where i am trying to reach timeSeries  
const service = new MiddlewareApi();
service.StepsCount().subscribe((timeSeries => console.log (timeSeries))); 
//timeSeires variable is in ^^^^^ this method StepsCount 

//This second method should return value of timeSeries into new method.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take a deeper look at RxJs and how to subscribe an Observable. 
I see a bit of misuses of services and caching stuff, anyway your service method `StepsCount` should return an Observable and the consumer (hopefully a component) should inject the service via constructor and do something like

```
service.StepsCount().subscribe(timeSeries => console.log(timeSeries));
```

Comment: tried RXJS method as you suggested the second method does not know what timeSeries is it is still undefined.

Comment: because the StepCount() function is returning an Observable of something that is still null. I don't  know which type returns the call to *getAllObservations*, but it should be an Observable and you should return its invocation with a pipe that transform and filter your timeSeries